# roots of $X^{p-1} -1$ in $\Bbb Q_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I don't know whether the Number of distinct roots of $X^{p-1} -1$ in $\Bbb Q_p$ is less or equal than $p-1$.

By a quick search I saw that $\Bbb Q_p$ is not algebraically closed so I can't really conclude.

Thank you for any help or reference on this subject.

Comment: The $(p-1)$-th roots of unity are pretty much well known to lie in $\Bbb Q_p$; and for $p>2$ these are all the roots of unity in this field. In $\Bbb Q_2$ you also have another root of unity, namely $-1$.

Comment: Hensel's lemma?

Comment: Indeed you should @KurtHensel.

Comment: Thank you! I see that Hensel's Lemma lifts a solution mod $p^k$ to a solution mod $p^{k+1}$  such that the new solution is compatible with the old one mod $p^k$ . But I don't see how this bounds the number of solutions of $X^{p-1} -1$ in $\Bbb Q_p$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295679/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576733/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49282/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2072148/96384.